# bound on a sum of Poisson random variables

Tags: probability, inequality, expected-value, poisson-distribution

Let $X_i$ be Poisson random variables, i.e. $P(X=k)=e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^k}{k!}, \quad k=0,1,2,...$. Let $X=\sum_{i=0}^ny_iX_i$, with $y_i\in R, \quad i=0,... n$ and let $r\geq 1$.

Is there an inequality of type:
$$
E(|X|^r)\leq Cf(y_i)g(X_i)?
$$

Comment: What is $x_i$ in your displayed equation?

Comment: Just an intuition, you can try the moment generating function for Poisson distribution.

Comment: @kimchi lover: sorry it is suppose to be capital $X_i$